# Unexpected result when initializing Timespan with ticks

Tags: c#, nunit, timespan, stopwatch, system.diagnostics

I am writing a unit test that will handle timing the iteration of all collection items through some functionality. In the unit test, I have setup SomeFunctionality to be a function the sleeps for 100ms.

```
public void SomeFunctionality(CollectionItem item)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

The unit tests look like this:

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
for(var item in collection)
{
    SomeFunctionality(item);
}
stopwatch.Stop();
```

where collection is a list with 3 objects in it. Next, I get the `totalElapsedTimeSpan` which represents the total time spent iterating through the entire collection (expected to be ~300ms) and `averageTimeSpan` which represents the average time spent on each item (expected to be ~100).

```
var totalElapsedTimeSpan = stopwatch.Elapsed;
var averageTicksPerItem = GetAverageTicksPerCollectionItem(_stopwatch.ElapsedTicks, collectionCount);
var averageTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(averageTicksPerItem);
```

where `averageTicksPerItem` is calculated as follows:

```
public long GetAverageTicksPerCollectionItem(long ticks, int count)
{
    return Convert.ToInt64(Math.Round(((double)ticks / count), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
}
```

Of course, the output isn't what we expected I expect it to be:

```
totalElapsedTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds: 302.4239
averageTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds: 25.5367
```

Just to make sure, I verified that the `GetAverageTicksPerCollection` function call wasn't causing some unexpected change.  The inputs and outputs of `GetAverageTicksPerCollectionItem` are:

```
ticks: 774720
count: 3
averageTicksPerItem: 258240
```

So that checks out. What is causing the value of the `averageTimeSpan` to be significantly lower than the expected ~100ms when passing `averageTicksPerItem` into the constructor?